# root Path is not working in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a site which is in online, two days back i create a new folder and uploaded the new version of the site in that folder and place the link button to redirect to new version site. when ever user click on the new version site it is redirecting to new version site. it is working fine when i click on any links of newversion site it is giving some path problems i try to modify that one even though it is not working. even i write direct url (http://www.xxx.com/New tfc/xx.aspx") but it is not working the site is "tfc18.com" can u try this once

The problem coming at user controls path the error like

```
<%@ Register Src="http://www.tfc18.com/NEW TFC/footer.ascx" TagName="footer" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
```

err is

```
'http://www.tfc18.com/NEW TFC/footer.ascx' is not a valid virtual path.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a virtual path like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/NEW TFC/footer.ascx" TagName="footer" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
```

This would tell the page to loook for a folder named "NEW TFC" in the root forlder of your application and then for a file named footer.ascx in it.

If you want to use files which are outside of the root folder of your application you have to use a custom virtual path provider.
Here is a list of sample implementations of virtual path providers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx
http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/VirtualPathProviderExample.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Virtual_Path_Provider.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a virtual path to the user control:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/NEW TFC/footer.ascx" TagName="footer" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
```

Comment: ya i tried that code it is giving this error like..

The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.

Comment: ya it is working i comment the xmlsitemap provider now it is working fine thank you